# AWS - Unable to Connect FROM (NOT TO) EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

Background: I have Jenkins running on my home Windows computer on port 80. I am trying to setup Jenkins Agent on EC2 Windows Instance. I wont go into any more details on Jenkins or background as I believe the issue pertains to the connectivity OUT FROM EC2 instance.

When I curl http://my.i.p.address inside the EC2 instance; it does not work. In the below code I have masked my IP address.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> curl http://my.i.p.address:80
curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://my.i.p.address:80
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], Webeption
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestComm
```

Notes:

- I have enabled the firewall to allow both the inbound and outbound
  traffic from any ip (just to test).
- I can curl to other ip addresses; e.g. www.google.com
- I can connect to EC2 instance from RDP
- My EC2 instance has Elastic IP associated with it.

Comment: What is `my.i.p.address`? Is that your router/gateway address? How did you get that address?

Comment: by running ipconfig on command prompt.

Comment: EC2 cannot connect to your home windows computer because it sits behind your router. Is your windows IP `172.x.x.x` or `10.x.x.x` or `192.x.x.x`?

Comment: `192.x.x.x`; how do i get an IP that EC2 can talk to?

Comment: Unless you put a hole in your router to forward the traffic from EC2 to your windows, it is not possible for EC2 to talk to your machine. There is something wrong with your flow. Revisit and fix it.

Comment: Ah, just googled on "putting the hole in my router". I would rather have an EC2 instance to host my Jenkins itself. Thanks. You helped me!!!